# sandbox for testing application

Tags: macos

I have developed an application and I want to test it in a fresh environment (e.g. as if this is a clean OSX, no custom `/usr/local`, a fresh `~/Library`, etc.). What would be the simplest way?

Comment: @Matteo: I really would like to. I just read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/unanswered-questions-and-accept-rate). For most of the answers on my questions so far, I feel that they don't perfectly answer my question in a way that they provided the information/solution I was searching for.

Comment: See here for two similar unanswered questions: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/102803/14319 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86516/14319

Answer (score 3):

Since Lion it is possible to run a virtual copy of Mac OS X on Apple hardware (e.g., with VirualBox, Parallels, VMWare).

You could install a clean copy, take a snapshot and use this fresh installation for tests.

Comment: That is quite a heavy/slow solution. Isn't there something simpler? I would guess it's maybe possible somehow with the buildin sandbox function. Or some chroot script.

Comment: Parallels & friends are not slow at all, you really should give it a try. The alternative would be to either buy a cheap Mac mini or install OS X on a second partition/drive.

Comment: @patrix: Why do you think that it is not possible via the builtin sandbox or via chroot?

Comment: You asked for the simplest way, not the most challenging. Even with ignoring the huge effort to setup OS X in a chroot environment at all: How do yo want to login into a chroot'ed environment in OS X? How would you chroot the System Event queue and other Cocoa-level stuff? Using VirtualBox or an installation on a second drive is *way simpler*. Or you can just create a new user if you are primarily interested in user-level sandboxing (which should be enough in most cases, you can even run the application directly from the home folder of the user).

Comment: It doesn't really matter for the System Event queue (at least in my cases but probably in most cases). I'm not sure what you mean about Cocoa-level stuff but I guess it also doesn't matter. All apps I know, or at least the apps I have in mind here, store their settings and read their settings just from the filesystem. Basically, user-level sandboxing would exactly do what I want. Or the builtin MacOSX sandbox feature would also exactly do what I want. I am mostly searching for some description how I could easily achieve it.