# Sandboxing certain OSX apps

Tags: macos, sandbox

I am running multiple modern internet and cloud related services. Is it possible to limit their access to parts of my filesystem? For example Dropbox only needs access to its Dropbox shared folder.

Comment: Do you suspect that Dropbox snoops on your system?

Comment: See for a similar unanswered question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/102803/14319