# How to isolate an application from the system (fully sandboxed application)?

Tags: ios, security, macos, sandbox

Is it possible to do something like the concept of **sandboxing** (like all apps on iOS have its own system software resources) for all existing applications (so - not while designing an own new application) on OSX (Lion/ML/Maverics) just copying required frameworks, libraries, binaries (`/usr, /etc, /Library`, etc.) and than using `chroot` for the process when start?

Comment: I guess creating separate user is not what you looking for or creating new partition with a copy of os ?

Comment: nope, I would like to have like a container inside an OS, so the kernel is one but there many executions environments with libraries proces namespaces etc. one for each running application/process. Thanks for asking for details

Comment: See for a similar unanswered question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/86516/14319

Comment: there is no answer there, only your recursive-link to here back again

Comment: I have used [*sandbox-exec*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sandbox-exec.1.html) to run a prebuilt program in an application sandbox that I created myself. This is not the same as the chroot “jail” approach you mentioned, but it is the core of the sandboxing required by the iOS and OS X app stores. Creating the sandbox profile is a non-trivial task and I do not know of any guides for it, but it may be something worth investigating.

Comment: Is this possibly what you are looking for? There is a guide at the bottom of the page in PDF - http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/osx-sandboxing-design

Comment: As @ChrisJohnsen mentioned, using `sandbox-exec` might be the solution, which you can find a related post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258318/is-there-a-sandboxing-program-like-sandboxie-for-mac

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is possible - iOS sandboxes all applications by default and runs on the same Darwin core as OS X. Apple hasn't chosen to implement this on OS X, so you would have a lot of engineering work to bolt this extra security on top of OS X. In the short run, it might be easier to virtualize the OS if you only need to sandbox one or two applications.