# Is running an app directly after opening .dmg file without installation safer than installing it?

Tags: macos, applications, install, dmg

For macos apps downloaded from the Internet, I am kinda paranoid and don't trust most of apps for security reasons, especially I am living in a country which does censorship too much.

I think there are three ways to run an app.

1. Open the .dmg file (basically mount it), double click the app to launch it directly.
2. Drag it to somewhere else (user space folder) other than the default Applications folder which requires root permission.
3. Drag it to the default Applications to install it.

I am wondering if I choose Option 1, can I say it's much safer way than the Option 3?

---

The above words are my question. The following words are just some optional questions. You can ignore all the following words.

If I choose Option 1, will it cause any issues when running such app? So far, I don't see any issues by using this way.

I am wondering if there are any better options here to run the app in a sandbox? (virtual machine is not an option here because I care about performance too. I don't want to pay extra cpu/ram resources to affect the performance)

Btw, I knew the best way to avoid such problem is to NOT run any apps I don't trust. But this is life, and I have to run the apps which I don't trust, otherwise I can not work and live in my society.

Comment: Running an application from a DMG does not automagically run it in a sandbox. Anyway, this looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about solutions)?

Comment: @nohillside thanks a lot for your reply. I don't think it's a XY problem. If you think it's not much safer to run an app from a DMG, then that is the answer. My question is whether it's safer to run it directly from a DMG than running it after installation. If there is no difference, then I will simply install it by dragging to /Applications. Basically I have to run apps which I downloaded online but I don't trust. I am trying to figure out if I should run them directly from DMG or I should install them, and which is safer.

Comment: The XY I see here is that you are on a quest to reduce the potential harm which can be caused by applications downloaded outside the app store. Running from a DMG doesn't help here.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258318/is-there-a-sandboxing-program-like-sandboxie-for-mac?rq=1

Comment: @nohillside I did find the URL you gave by googling. I think the answer to my question is "not safer at all" to run an app from DMG directly than installing and run it. If you think this is not an answer and it's still XY question, I can delete this question as you request. Thanks a lot for your time and help. :)

Comment: No reason to delete, I'm sure somebody will post a more complete answer in due time.

Comment: Note that you are worried about safety then run in a VM - The performance difference won't uysually matter. If it does then you can see if the app is useful first then bother about speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Open the .dmg file (basically mount it), double click the app to launch it directly.
> 2. Drag it to somewhere else (user space folder) other than the default Applications folder which requires root permission.
> 3. Drag it to the default Applications to install it.
>
> I am wondering if I choose Option 1, can I say it's much safer way than the Option 3?

None of these methods provide additional protection. If the application intends to do harm, nothing in the options above will stop the harm being done.

**If you do not trust an application, the source, or the developers, do not run the application.**

If you *must* run an untrusted application, consider a constrained runtime environment such as a virtual machine. You mention performance rules out the use of a virtual machine; this is a security trade off.

If a virtual machine is not possible, create a separate non-administrator user account and only run the application using that account. This will provide some additional protection but your machine is still at risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I think I will consider using `sandbox-exec` to restrict folder access. I think this way will have better performance than VM.

Comment: Please note `sandbox-exec` is deprecated, see `man sandbox-exec`. Apple has since introduced a broader sandboxing mechanism in macOS.