# Permission of a binary executable to access certain files?

Tags: permission, filesystem

In macOS we can set in settings whether an app can access document/download/etc folders.

Now, how can one do access control on arbitrary directories and particular files, not just the a few ones above?

Also, instead of controlling an app, can we instead control an executable binary?

Of course, please mention 3rd party software if necessary.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the use cases/problems you want to solve here? Access control for sure is possible (see `man chmod`)  but it's not clear whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @nohillside Have you read the question at all? The chmod command is not relevant. I am asking about permission for an app, not a file.

Comment: This is an interesting question as there is certainly a balance where Apple does not want to cause too many privacy/security prompts for normal users but it would be great to be able to set greater restrictions on apps in the GUI privacy settings. Thankfully there is more advanced functionality underneath: does [this existing question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336276/37797) solve your problem? macOS has robust sandboxing built in that lets you restrict processes to certain paths with `file-write-data` and `file-read-data`/`file-read-metadata` restrictions.

Comment: Ma Joad, I may have misunderstood the "how can one do access control on arbitrary directories and particular files" part. Hope the link provided by grg is more helpful.